# Xamarin Forms iOS 2 Modal Pages Restriction

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have been creating app using Xamarin Forms for a while now, I have one app that requires 5 Modal Pages stacked one after the other.

The app is a Shell App.

I have used 'App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync()' to show 5 Modal Pages one on top of another.  This works fine on Android, meaning that all the 5 Modal Pages are stacked one after the other.

But on iPhone it only show/stack the first 2 Modal Pages, the rest are not shown. Is this some kind of restriction? Or can I override this somewhere?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.0) which is the latest at the time or writing (May 23 2023).

PS:  The app is a Shell App and have Tab Pages and Flyout Menu Items.

I don't want to use 'App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync()' as it doesn't look good on the app.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please do not post duplicates